# Как открыть страницу и получить Cookies

Tags: c#, cefsharp

У меня простая задача, перейти на страницу что бы на ней отработали js скрипты и получить куки которые на данный момент в контейнере.
Пробовал через

```
var cookieManager = Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager();
var visitor = new CookieCollector();

cookieManager.VisitUrlCookies(myUrl, true, visitor);
```

Но страница в браузере не открывается, и скрипты (на сколько я понимаю) не отрабатывают. Есть вариант открыть страницу через `await Browser.LoadUrlAsync()` и получить все куки с контейнера?

Comment: А что за сайт и что с него надо получить вы сказать можете? Ведь в большинстве случаев браузер для таких целей не нужен, достаточно простых запросов.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да не важно какой сайт, я хочу сделать из этого браузера сервис позволяющий делать то, что я описал, для запросов у меня уже есть другой сервис. Вопрос все еще актуален. Мне нужно что бы именно страница открывалась и что бы я видел что происходит на странице, это мне нужно для дебага, нужно открыть страницу и что бы я ее видел глазами и тогда уже мог в коде менять логику согласно того, что я физически вижу, а то открытие страницы в бэекграунде это то, что будет в готовом сервисе, но для дебага мне нужно открыть страницу стандартно